# Alarm system call on Ubuntu 12.4

Tags: c, ubuntu, signals, virtualbox

I personally hate these kind of questions, but I'm stuck. I have a program that I'm trying to run on **Ubuntu 12.4** *(kernal: Linux 3.2.0-39-generic-pae #62-Ubuntu SMP i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux; compiler: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3)*:

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <signal.h>
#include    <unistd.h>

/*
 * sleep1.c
 *      purpose show how sleep works
 *      usage   sleep1
 *      info    sets handler, sets alarm, pauses, then returns
 */

int main()
{
    void    onbell(int);

    printf("about to sleep for 4 seconds\n");
    signal(SIGALRM, onbell);            /* catch it */
    alarm(4);                   /* set clock    */
    pause();                    /* do nothing   */
    printf("Morning so soon?\n");           /* back to work */
    return 0;
}

void
onbell(int s)
{
    printf("Alarm received from kernel\n");
}
```

The problem is, the *SIGALRM* never comes through.  If I run *strace* on it, the last three lines are:

```
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x80484c1, [ALRM], SA_RESTART}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
alarm(4)                                = 0
pause(
```

Pause never returns.  When I run the same code on a system that reports itself with *Kernal: Linux 2.6.24-32-generic i686 GNU/Linux; Compiler: gcc (GCC) 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4)* the same code running with strace on it shows:

```
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x8048470, [ALRM], SA_RESTART}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
alarm(4)                                = 0
pause()                                 = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted)
--- SIGALRM (Alarm clock) @ 0 (0) ---
write(1, "Alarm received from kernel\n", 27Alarm received from kernel
) = 27
```

Any idea why the alarm is never picked up on **Ubuntu 12.4** system or what can be done to figure out what's going on?

Comment: "When I run the same code on another system", already compiled? Or compiling it from source again?

Comment: compiling from source on the other system

Comment: Can you post your compiler versions for each and kernel version?

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña, yes, I added them in. Also just tested copying binary from ubuntu to other linux system and the SIGALRM is coming through there.

Comment: Oh okay, so taking the compiled binary from the problem-system does work on the other system? I'm not to keen on crying "system (kernel, compiler, etc.) bug" but I can't account for anything else. Maybe someone else has another idea. You're compiling very simply? No complicated makefiles which might use [feature test macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) like `_BSD_SOURCE`?

Comment: It looks like it may be the kernal; in that something altered the alerting system, perhaps in a recent update.  I just tested on another 12.4 box (kernal 3.2.0-29-generic-pae, so 10 revisions older) and it works :/ May be interesting to update to the same kernal and see if it's a kernal issue or not.

Comment: Ah okay, at least it works now I suppose.

Comment: If you were testing running linux in virtual box, see https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10585

Comment: @Gonzalo, thanks, I am.  I have two with 12.4 though, and one works and one doesn't :)  I'm going with something happened to the one box.

Answer (score 1):

you can not safely call printf(), or a fair number of other i/o functions from within a signal handler.  It sometimes works, but it isn't reliable.  It's not async-signal safe.  See this for a list of others: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

It will sometimes "accidentally" work however, making people think it is generally acceptable.

Try incrementing a variable inside the signal handler instead, then checking for it's value changing outside the signal handler.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I emptied the _bell_ function of all content and the process still never gets through the _pause_ function.

Comment: Apart from that, I can't see anything wrong with what you're doing, and, although I'm sure you don't want to hear this, it works fine here, but I'm not running Ubuntu.  Any chance you can compile it on another system (not Ubuntu, some other Linux distro) and copy it over to see what happens?  Might be a toolchain/library issue.

Comment: :) Thanks, just tried pulling the compiled version from the second machine onto the Ubuntu machine and the same behaviour is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the possibility that the signal is never fired. After all, strace shows that `rt_sigaction` returns 0 indicating success in setting the signal disposition. I think the `SIGALRM` signal is never being sent at all.

**EDIT**: It seems this was the case. I hope @Gonzalo doesn't mind me referencing the VirtualBox [ticket he posted](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10585) titled "The SIGALRM never fires". You said you were testing on virtual box. It does seem to reflect this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the code, it's a good thought.  Switching it doesn't help, process still never gets through the pause function.

Comment: I agree with this analysis,

Comment: @Nate Yeah, it's a rare thing to blame the kernel (since we ruled out the compiler). At first I suspected it might be the kernel but then again I wasn't aware you were running in a VirtualBox environment haha. Hope your problem is solved now.